# Как, нажав на кнопку, проскроллить вниз до определённого блока?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть эта кнопка - `<svg class="liquid-button"></svg>`
Мне нужно при нажатии на неё скроллить к блоку, у которого `id="cost"`.
Это не якоря навигации! Якоря я уже сделал.
Необходим простой скролл при нажатии на кнопку и всё.
Как это сделать?
Нигде не могу найти ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.block {
  height: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bottom-block {
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('.bottom-block').scrollIntoView()">scroll</button>
  <div class="bottom-block"></div>
</div>
```